# Delphi Not Loading Jpg Image - Thinks it's a Bitmap?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, jpeg

I have an issue where I'm trying to load a Jpg image in Delphi.

My calling line of code is:

```
AImage.Picture.LoadFromFile( AImageFilePathStr );
```

I've followed it though to the Vcl.Graphics TFileFormatsList.FindExt method.

There I've added a watch (some variables like 'I' were inaccessible due to optimization), but FindExt matches when I=8. 4th item matches and 'I' counts down from 11 to 0.

A watch on `TFileFormatType(Items[8])` expands to `GraphicClass is TBitmap and Extension is 'jpg'`. So the extension matches, but the GraphicClass is TBitmap.

An exception is later thrown "Bitmap image is not valid".

Why does Delphi seem to think this Jpg image is a bitmap?

Thanks.

Comment: The only way `.jpg` would map to `TBitmap` is if user code outside of the VCL has mis-registered it using `TPicture.RegisterFileFormat()` incorrectly. Add the standard `Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg` unit to your `uses` clause to register JPG correctly.

Comment: This question can't be answered as is. You need a [mcve] to explain the otherwise inexplicable behaviour. Well, I suppose it easy enough to presume that the format has been misregistered by something but the unanswerable part is what that something is.

Comment: My apologies. I will do so in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg` to the `uses` clause in my main unit was the answer.

I don't understand the why yet, but that fixed it. :-)

Comment: Additional info:

Comment: There are no user calls to TPicture.RegisterFileFormat. By adding the Jpeg to my uses, the Vcl.Graphics TFileFormatsList.FindExt upped its Count to 14 registered classes. The latest ones added take precedence and correctly match extension jpg to TJPEGImage.

Comment: That does not explain why `TBitmap` was originally registered for JPG. The VCL's native class registrations do not do that, so it had to be something else in your project that did it.

Comment: The VCL's native class registrations actually do misregister classes in the constructor of TFileFormatsList. Png, gif, jpeg, and jpg extensions are all registered as type TBitmap by default. Adding later registrations with an extension supersede the earlier registrations by the VCL. I've sent this to QualityCentral since the "Bitmap image is not valid" should be replaced by the generic "Unknown picture file extension" that already exists in the VCL.

Comment: Any code inside of `{$IF DEFINED(CLR)}` is for Delphi.NET, which disappeared many years ago (but still exists in the source code). In Win32, the `TFileFormatsList` constructor registers `TBitmap` for `bmp` files only. In .NET, it registers `TBitmap` for multiple formats because `TBitmap` uses .NET's [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class to support various formats and extract their pixel data. That is not the case in Win32, where each format is a separate class (except for the case of WIC)

Comment: Unless this has changed after 10.0 Seattle (the last version I have installed).  In Seattle, the `TFileFormatsList` constructor still registers `TBitmap` for `bmp` files only in Win32.

Comment: I added comments to your [QualityPortal ticket](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18486) (it is not QualityCentral).